# Image off-set in slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slideshow

I am making a slideshow, but the images are messed up and I can't find the problem.

http://epicureancateringaz.com/New/index

There is something making a gap on the images on the slideshow.

```
<div id="slideshow">
        <ul>
<li id="photos1"><a href=""><img src="images/photos/1.jpg" alt="img 1" /></a></li>
<li id="photos2"><a href=""><img src="images/photos/2.jpg" alt="img 2" /></a></li>
<li id="photos3"><a href=""><img src="images/photos/3.jpg" alt="img 3" /></a></li>
<li id="photos4"><a href=""><img src="images/photos/4.jpg" alt="img 4" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="slideshow-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#photos1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos3"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos4"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");
$("#slideshow-nav").css("visability", "visable");
$("#slideshow-nav a[href=#photos1]").addClass("active");

$("#slideshow-nav").localScroll({
    target:'#slideshow', axis: 'x'
});

$("#slideshow-nav a").click(function(){
    $("#slideshow-nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure `"visability","visable"` should be `"visibility","visible"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a problem with your CSS for the gap at the top, is this the gap you're referring to?

Div and UL are both block elements. Under ul put the following style:

```
ul {
   margin-top: 0;
}
```

Alternatively, the gap on the left could be solved with the following css:

```
li {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: then why does the first image have a gap on the left, then when you go to a different image and go back, its gone.

Comment: Apologies, see edited answer. A gap did appear in the top for me (chrome) but hasn't come back since.... strange.

Comment: yeah, doing position absolute messes the whole website up.

Comment: You will have to make it specific to just the li's under the slideshow div. Give the li's under the slideshow div a specific class, then apply the style i outlined above to that class.

Comment: I fixed it. Instead of position:absolute, i did a margin-left:-40px

Comment: I'm glad you've fixed it, sorry I couldn't have been of more assistance.

Comment: it was... the ul margin-top helped get rid of the top gap. Ill be the judge if it helped me...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#slideshow ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```